# Accessing fields from a struct

Tags: c#, field

I have a struct named MyHouse for example.

```
struct MyHouse
{
    int Light;
    int Water;
    int Food;

    public MyHouse(int Light, int Water, int Food)
    {
        this.Light = Light;
        this.Water = Water;
        this.Food = Food;
    }
}
```

City class:

```
class City
{
    private MyHouse house;
    public City(MyHouse house)
    {
        this.house = house;
    }
    public MyHouse GetHouse()
    {
        return house;
    }
}
```

In main for example I create

```
 City c = new City(new MyHouse(3,6,1));
```

where `City` is the `class` where `struct MyHouse` is. If I want to get the number of light from `MyHouse`, accessed from the `City` class how would I do?

Comment: c.GetHouse().Light; ?

Comment: `MyHouse` should also be a `class`.

Comment: @DieterB Light won't be accessible because of protection level

Comment: @TimSchmelter, beyond the "structs only have edge-case usages and this isn't one of them" reasoning, why do you suggest it be a class?

Comment: @DavidArno:just because a `House` is something that could be changed. It's a typical case for a `class`. Most types should be classes and nothing was mentioned that suggests using a `struct`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx): _"AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
It is immutable.
It will not have to be boxed frequently."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter, as it currently stands, it does represent a single value (a house), it is under 16 bytes and it is immutable. Of course, the OP may not want it to be immutable, at which point a class would be the right choice (with the caveat that making it mutable is the wrong choice).

Comment: @DavidArno: by  your definition every type represents a single value(an instance). Make it a struct if a class is clearly not appropriate, not the other way around. Otherwise C# is not the right language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify any property like public, protected or private, C# makes the variable private for "struct". So either you need to make the variable public so that you can access it directly or add a public method, to access the private variable.

Comment: No, do not make it public as you are then creating a mutable struct, which breaks one of the rules around what makes a good struct

Comment: Good practice does not mean a "must". I was saying that was a way to access the variable. One can do that if it fits his situation, but it's not a good way to go in general. Correct me if I am wrong @DavidArno

Answer (score 2):

Add a property in MyHouse so that private data can be accessed :

```
private int light;
public int Light{
  get { return light; }
}
```

Then you can write :

```
int l = c.GetHouse().Light;
```

Of course `GetHouse()` could be turned into a property

```
public MyHouse House{
  get { return house; }
  set {light = house;}
}
```

Properties are "better" than methods, because :

- They can easily be used **while debugging** - **hover mouse above property** and see value
- They are **often used by frameworks** (Entity frameworks, graphical components). Propertie are used for automatic display of columns

Properties are "better" than direct access to fields because:

-If client code is used to access the property, some **code can be added later** to the property `get` or `set`
 without any change to the client
-If they are `virtual`, they can be `overriden` in sub classes

Comment: Sorry, somebody edited, while I was, so I didn't see the result. Sorry for collision. Underscore are ok but not necessary and not necessary so nice. It 's a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: No that's ok, it 's better to keep courteous, open minded and tolerant, especially on a forum ;-)

Comment: This is bad too `set {light = house;}` in `House`. Just use `{get;set;}`.

Answer (score 2):

If in `MyHouse` you modify

```
int Light;
```

to be

```
public int Light {get; private set;}
```

You can get the light value from a `City` object like this:

```
c.GetHouse().Light
```

Explanation:

`public` changes the visibility of `Light` from `private` (which is the default) to `public`. A private class/struct member can only be accessed internally by the class itself. To make if available to other classes, like `City` in this case, I have made it public.

`{get; private set;}` turns `Light` from a simple field to a property, basically a field whose access is wrapped around a getter and a setter method. In your example the value of `Light` is only set in the constructor for `MyHouse`, so I've made the setter `private`. This means that only `MyHouse` can change the value of `Light`; however, `City` can still get the value.

Comment: In addition to the above, if you are using C# 6, you do not need the `private set;`. `Light` can be defined as `public int Light {get;}` and the constructor can still write to it.

Comment: That's true, and I should also add that the solution works with C# 3 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this:

```
int i = c.GetHouse().Light;
```

But only if `Light` is `public`. Now it isn't and that prevents you from accessing the field.

You can make properties out of your fields. I would suggest to make `Light` a `class` too:

```
class MyHouse
{
    public int Light {get;set;}
    public int Water {get;set;}
    public int Food {get;set;}

    public MyHouse(int light, int water, int food)
    {
        this.Light = light;
        this.Water = water;
        this.Food = food;

    }
}
```

I'd also expect `City` to have a list of `House`s, not just one. Maybe you should make `GetHouse()` a `List<House> Houses` property.